# Any numeric measure to indicate seasonality, uncertainty of demand?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, seasonality

Am working on inventory management, demand forecasting etc. As part of this project, I am exploring the data to see the past demand of the products to predict the future.

While am currently plotting few plots to know the seasonal trends of the products and computing "Coefficient of Variation" to determine the product uncertainity based on article that I read [here](https://medium.com/@ulas_yilmaz/abc-xyz-inventory-classification-with-python-50ebee552fe4). But plotting for 6000 plus products in our company is not feasible.

Hence, my question is there any automated way/ python package which can give numeric insights on a scale of 0-1 which we can explore and classify them based on business experience/review?

[image]

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp3/stlfeatures.html

Comment: @RobHyndman - I went through the link that you shared and has lot of useful info. But , by any chance, do we have any python packages that can do the same (instead of R)?

Comment: https://github.com/Nixtla/tsfeatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, there is lively research in time series features, dimensionality reduction and clustering, coming out of Rob Hyndman and colleagues' lab, e.g., [Montero-Manso et al. (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.011) and [Talagala et al. (2022)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2021.07.002), so you might want to take a look at how they define their features like seasonal or trend strength.

Then again, that all does not map feature strength to the interval $[0,1]$. For that, one possibility would be to model your time series using a straightforward linear model and feeding in seasonal or trend predictors. Then you could use something like $R^2$ for the proportion of variance explained, which is inherently between 0 and 1. For "uncertainty", you could use one minus the overall $R^2$ of your model. Beware of overfitting!

Alternatively, since you are interested in forecasting, you could do something similar with different forecasting models and a holdout sample. As a baseline, use a model without trend or seasonality. Compare that to a model with trend - by how much does that reduce the error in the holdout period? (Which could well be negative, if your trended model forecasts worse than a nontrended one. Which in turn I would take as evidence that the series itself is not trended.)

In any case, you will likely want to further filter your table by some notion of "importance" of the series, e.g., its overall level, so you don't get swamped by highly seasonal and completely irrelevant series.